# Left and Right identity of a BiFunction?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

When I create a Map from stream, I use:

```
Map<Bar, Foo> fooBar = stream
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Foo::getBar,
        Function.identity(),
        (x, y) -> x
    ));
```

The merge function I need is just the first. We have `Function.identity()` that we can pass as a lambda. Do we have something similar for `BiFunction`, such as `BiFunction.left()`? External library can work as well.

Answer (score 2):

No.  It's simplest, and most efficient, to do exactly what you have done.  (Honestly, `x -> x` is often simpler and clearer than `Function.identity()` as well.)

Comment: I agree.  I really don't know why `Function.identity` was included.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the documentation of [`BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html#method-summary) you'll find out that the only methods it defines are `maxBy()` and `minBy()`. And it also inherits `apply()` and `andThen()` from `BiFunction`.

Nothing similar to what you're looking for.

If you feel like you really need such method `left()` you can extend `BinaryOperator` and define one:

```
public interface MyBinaryOperator<T> extends BinaryOperator<T> {
    static <T> BinaryOperator<T> left() {
        return (left, right) -> left;
    }
}
```

Applying to your example:

```
foos.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Foo::getBar,
        Function.identity(),
        MyBinaryOperator.left()
    ));
```